# Does Direct2D use back-buffer?

Tags: direct2d

Reading https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct2d/comparing-direct2d-and-gdi :

> Presentation Model
>
> When Windows was
> first designed, there was insufficient
> memory to allow every window to be
> stored in its own bitmap. As a result,
> GDI always rendered logically directly
> to the screen, with various clipping
> regions applied to ensure that it did
> not render outside of its window. In
> contract, Direct2D follows a model
> where the application renders to a
> back-buffer and the result is
> atomically “flipped” when the
> application is done drawing. This
> allows Direct2D to handle animation
> scenarios much more fluidly that GDI
> can.

The author says Direct2D uses back-buffer and by 'flipped' he meant swap-chain I guess. I created a simple demo that draw a rectangle at random location on mouse click. But previous rectangles are not cleared so it seems that it is drawn directly to the screen and does not use any back-buffer.

Answer (score 4):

When you initialize the RenderTarget for your Direct2D operations you can specify in the second parameter the D2D1_PRESENT_OPTIONS option.

I think what confuses you is the D2D1_PRESENT_OPTIONS_RETAIN_CONTENTS and the fact that the buffer isn't swapped but copied.

Answer (score 1):

That doesn't disprove the existence of back-buffers, it only means the back-buffer isn't cleared between redraws. Right observation, wrong conclusion!

If you increase the number of back-buffers in the chain, you'll start noticing flickering rectangles as you keep clicking, so you should always clear your back-buffer between redraws.

Comment: If I click twice exactly two rectangles appear. If back-buffer is used that shouldn't be the case I think.

Comment: I guess if back-buffer is used it's swapped every time I call the BeginDraw. So if I draw two rectangles using two BeginDraw calls then one rectangle goes to buffer 1 and another rectangle to buffer 2. Then we should see only one rectangle.

Comment: You said there's only one back buffer though.

Comment: One front-buffer, one back-buffer

Answer (score 1):

Direct2D indeed uses back-buffer.

Perhaps you forgot to clear your render target, which is the back-buffer, right after calling begindraw and so previous draws stayed there?